# Parse KML from google maps to array

Tags: php, arrays, kml

I need to collect all the coordinates from a google maps `kml` file in a single array.

The `kml` content is:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<kml xmlns='http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2'>
    <Document>
        <name>lago maggiore</name>
        <description><![CDATA[]]></description>
        <Folder>
            <name>Livello senza titolo</name>
            <Placemark>
                <name>Linea 1</name>
                <description><![CDATA[prima parte]]></description>
                <styleUrl>#line-000000-1</styleUrl>
                <ExtendedData>
                </ExtendedData>
                <LineString>
                    <tessellate>1</tessellate>
                    <coordinates>8.6048698,45.7246374,0.0 8.603754,45.7248771,0.0</coordinates>
                </LineString>
            </Placemark>
            <Placemark>
                <name>Linea 2</name>
                <description><![CDATA[seconda parte]]></description>
                <styleUrl>#line-000000-1</styleUrl>
                <ExtendedData>
                </ExtendedData>
                <LineString>
                    <tessellate>1</tessellate>
                    <coordinates>8.8187063,46.1729734,0.0 8.8187706,46.172913900000005,0.0</coordinates>
                </LineString>
            </Placemark>
            <Placemark>
                <name>Linea 3</name>
                <description><![CDATA[terza parte]]></description>
                <styleUrl>#line-000000-1</styleUrl>
                <ExtendedData>
                </ExtendedData>
                <LineString>
                    <tessellate>1</tessellate>
                    <coordinates>8.617798100000002,45.9111526,0.0 8.6177766,45.9110257,0.0</coordinates>
                </LineString>
            </Placemark>
        </Folder>
        <Folder>
            <name>Livello senza titolo</name>
        </Folder>
        <Folder>
            <name>Livello senza titolo</name>
        </Folder>
        <Style id='line-000000-1-normal'>
            <LineStyle>
                <color>ff000000</color>
                <width>1</width>
            </LineStyle>
        </Style>
        <Style id='line-000000-1-highlight'>
            <LineStyle>
                <color>ff000000</color>
                <width>2.0</width>
            </LineStyle>
        </Style>
        <StyleMap id='line-000000-1'>
            <Pair>
                <key>normal</key>
                <styleUrl>#line-000000-1-normal</styleUrl>
            </Pair>
            <Pair>
                <key>highlight</key>
                <styleUrl>#line-000000-1-highlight</styleUrl>
            </Pair>
        </StyleMap>
    </Document>
</kml>
```

I tried this but I got always the 1 coords node instead of all of them (3)
(`$poligono` is the correct `kml` file)

```
    $xml = simplexml_load_file($poligono) or die("file non caricato");
        $coords   = array();

        foreach($xml->Document->Folder->Placemark->children() as $element)
        {
            foreach($element as $key => $val)
            {
                foreach($xml->Document->Folder->Placemark->LineString as $element)
                {
                    foreach($element as $key => $val)
                    {
                        // echo "{$key}: {$val}" . "<br>";
                        if ({$key}== 'coordinates')
                        {
                          $args     = explode(",", {$val});
                          $coords[] = array($args[0], $args[1], $args[2]);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

The goal is to collect in the array $coords[] all the coordinates even if they are subdivided into different sub-lines (different nodes inside the google maps `kml`). Where is my mistake?
Thanks for help.

Comment: you're re-using `$element` in two loops, and $key/$val in two other loops. All four loops are basically stomping on each others' toes. In other words, fix your variable names...

Comment: What does this have to do with the [google-maps-api-3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-maps-api-3)?

Comment: sorry ... i was working also on another script conerning googlemaps api3 .. it's a mistake.. how can i erase that tag from here? thnx

Comment: thnx marc ... going to try